# Pivot a Pandas dataframe multiple times with variable column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a dataframe:

```
person_id =  [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
subscription_id = [96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105]
kwart = [19,19,20,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
kwart_2 = [20,20,21,22,21,22,23,23,25,27]
kwart_3 = [21,20,21,22,22,23,24,25,26,30]

s = {"Person_ID": person_id, "Subscription_ID": subscription_id, "Event1": kwart, "Event2": kwart_2, "Event3": kwart_3}
data = pd.DataFrame(data = s)
```

which looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to pivot the table by the subscription ID and aggregate it so that 1 Person_Id has one row, and all events are listed in it. The column names should correspond to the row in which they were listed, for example Event1_1, Event1_2 etc.

Expected output:
[image]

Is there a way to do this in Pandas?
I was thinking to do it with pivot_table function but I am not sure how to pass the columns argument.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976592/pandas-pivot-table-incremental-column-names) your answer to the question??

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem is similar to this [pandas pivot based on unique values and criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105972/pandas-pivot-based-on-unique-values-and-criteria).
Check it out, hope it helpfull.